# How to enable CertOpenSystemStoreW in the cpp-httplib library

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I am developing a UWP C++/winRT app in Visual Studio, and am trying to get the [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib) library to work. It works fine if I am not using HTTPS, but when I define the CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT flag, an "#ifdef" in httplib.h defines a function which subcalls CertOpenSystemStoreW(), which results in an error that CertOpenSystemStoreW() is undeclared.

On tracing deeper into <wincrypt.h>, it seems that CertOpenSystemStoreW is part of an unactivated code region because of my configuration.

What can I do to reactivate the region, or what should I replace CertOpenSystemStoreW() with, to make SSL work? (CertOpenStore() seems to work, but I don't really understand SSL details enough to know if I can simply replace the function)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "USDA_API.h"
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT
#include <httplib.h>
//#include <cpr/cpr.h>

USDA_API::USDA_API()
{
    httplib::Client cli("http://www.google.com");

    auto resp = cli.Get("/");
    int y = 4;
}
```

Is there an easier way to send HTTPS requests (GET, POST, etc.) in C++/winRT that I don't know about? If C++/winRT is an extension to UWP, and UWP is invalidating CertOpenSystemStoreW() in wincrypt.h, how are people sending HTTPS requests in UWP C++ apps?

Comment: `CertOpenSystemStoreW` is available for desktop applications only. You cannot use it in a UWP application. The [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient) supports HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! I was able to send HTTPS responses using HttpClient. I also copy-pasted "json.hpp" into my project from [a header-only json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json), since Windows.Data.Json wasn't being recognized by VS for some reason.

I successfully was able to get a HTTPS response and parse the data !